# start_test_server_in_background throws NoMethodError: undefined method 'path' for nil:NilClass

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

I have two machines that work just fine, but the most resent machine that I am configuring is not able to start the test server in the console.

Screenshot:
[image: Console output]

I have been banging my head against it all day and I cannot figure out what is going wrong. Is there anything obvious that I am missing that would cause this?

**Update**
This issue, at least for me, was caused by having a relative path in my APP_BUNDLE_PATH. I had APP_BUNDLE_PATH="~/Documents/workspace/...". As soon as I made that the full explicit path I no longer got the errors trying to start up a test server.

Comment: Please run with debug logging and paste the hash table that is generated to this issue.  You can run with debug logging by doing one of the following: $ DEBUG=1 calabash-ios console or > verbose (in the IRB itself).  Is this a Xamarin Studio project by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are tracking this bug here:

[`nil` path when preparing simulator in compatible arches check when APP was not set correctly](https://github.com/calabash/run_loop/issues/463)

Until it is fixed, set the `APP` environment variable.

```
$ APP=./path/to/my.app calabash-ios console
```

#### UPDATE

The problem has been fixed in the develop branch and will be available in run_loop 2.3.1.

The cause of the problem is that some combination of `APP`, `APP_BUNDLE_PATH`, and `BUNDLE_ID` is incorrect for a simulator target.

Either:

1. APP or APP_BUNDLE_PATH does not point to directory that exists.  If you are setting one of these variables, make sure the .app bundle exists.
2. You are targeting a simulator one of the three variables above is being set to a bundle identifier, e.g. APP=com.example.MyApp.  It is invalid to use a bundle identifier when targeting a simulator.

If you are not explicitly setting any variables when launch the console, see if they are defined in the environment.

```
$ echo $APP
$ echo $APP_BUNDLE_PATH
$ echo $BUNDLE_ID
```

If they are not defined and you are still getting this error, please open an issue with debug logging.

```
$ DEBUG=1 calabash-ios console
> start_test_server_in_background

$ calabash-ios console
> verbose
> start_test_server_in_background
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It was the first issue. The console doesn't seem to like relative paths.